# Compilation of Python 3.6.5 on Debian 9 hangs on test_asyncio

Tags: linux, debian, python, compilation

Compilation steps:

```
apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
apt-get install -y libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm
apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev  libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev
tar xvf Python-3.6.5.tgz
cd Python-3.6.5
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local/python365
make -j20
```

I've tried this and similar ways of compiling Python and it's always the same, it hangs on:

```
0:00:28 load avg: 0.90 [ 25/406] test_asyncio
```

Comment: Do you really have 20 or more CPU cores?

Comment: Yes, I have 24 cores on that box.

Comment: Maybe you've run into a race condition. Unfortunately it happens sometimes, as most people don't develop their software on such systems. Try it with `-j1` and see if it works (slowly). If it does, file a bug report. If it doesn't, file a bug report.